# SubSonic 2.0 Delete() is 'method' bus is used like a 'type'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, subsonic2.2

I've recently had to adopt a SubSonic based solution, and i'm getting an error
for Delete Insert and Update

Delete is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'

```
    public static Delete Delete()
    {            
        return Repository.Delete();
    }
```

I can tell there is supposed to be a type Delete, but for some reason it's not being shown, am I missing a reference?
I've got SubSonic.dll (version 2.0.3) referenced in a Visual Studio 2010 WebSite

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database table must have a primary key in order to support CRUD operations.  In addition to this, you should have a ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, CreatedBy, CreatedOn, IsDeleted column if you want to use the built-in change tracking.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me reach the solution, but it was different from this, the SubCode i was using to generate the code was a different version of the dll i had included. So in the end i just needed to re-reference the dll's from the same version, (i adopted the project so my downloaded and installed one was different).